# Error in git push heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have seen many question on Stackoverflow a bit similar to my question but none have faced same problem which I am having while I try to push my app to heroku.

My Ruby On Rails app is created on rails 3.2.17 and ruby v. 1.9.3 and currently it is in local setup I want to push it to heroku server.. but always I keep getting the same error, this is the full response which I am getting in 'git Bash prompt'

```
    $ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 1708, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1640/1640), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1708/1708), 47.02 MiB | 150.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1708 (delta 207), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Warning:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled p
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in yo
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your d
 all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfi
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path v
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
       Fetching source index from http://ruby.taobao.org/
       Resolving dependencies.....................................
       Network error while fetching
       http://rubygems-china.oss.aliyuncs.com/quick/Marshal.4.8/tr
emspec.rz
       Bundler Output: Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_a
       Fetching source index from http://ruby.taobao.org/
       Resolving dependencies.....................................
       Network error while fetching
       http://rubygems-china.oss.aliyuncs.com/quick/Marshal.4.8/tr
emspec.rz
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself, actually in my Gemfile source was set as 'http://ruby.taobao.org' and i guess there was some kind of network conflict   between http://ruby.taobao.org and heroku server during the process of installing gems. I changed the source to 'http://rubygems.org' and it worked.